# How to move Unity launcher icons to desktop?

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, .desktop

everyone.
OK, I have what may be a very simple question--how do I take an icon from the Unity Launcher that I had locked there, and move them onto the desktop?  I have tried everything I can think of and cannot get it to work, the icons just slide back the Launcher!

Comment: Oh, wait, I just found that I could drag the applications from the Dash and it would work. :P  Silly me.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you can't drag an icon from the launcher onto the desktop.

Instead search for the application in the application lens or the dash an drag the icon from there onto the desktop.